# Swift UnsafeMutableRawPointer Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unsafemutablepointer

With Swift 3, I got this, without any errors:

```
private var SessionRunningContext = 0

func addObservers() {
   self.session.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "running", options: .new, context: &SessionRunningContext)
}

func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
   let newValue: AnyObject? = change![NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as AnyObject?
   switch context! {
     case &SessionRunningContext:
         // Do something
   }
}
```

However, when I build this on iOS 12, Xcode Beta, I get an error saying:

> Use of extraneous '&'

for this line:

```
case &SessionRunningContext:
```

Comment: Interesting, looks like a temporary bug. It's fixed on master (can't currently confirm whether it's fixed in the latest Swift 4.2 snapshot though). As a workaround, you could do `case let x where x == &SessionRunningContext:`.

Comment: ... or `switch context { case .some(&SessionRunningContext): ...` or `if context == &SessionRunningContext { ...`

Comment: (and it is indeed fixed in the latest 4.2 snapshot)

Comment: It is fixed in Xcode 10 beta 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That seems to be a bug in the Swift that comes with Xcode 10 beta 3,
It has been fixed in Xcode 10.0 beta 4 (10L213o).

Possible workarounds for Xcode 10 beta 3 are:

A pattern with a where-clause (attribution goes to @Hamish for this one):

```
switch context {
    case let x where x == &SessionRunningContext:
    // Do something

}
```

An optional pattern:

```
switch context {
    case .some(&SessionRunningContext):
    // Do something

}
```

A simple if-statement:

```
if context == &SessionRunningContext {
     // Do something

}
```

Note also that only the address of a global variable or static property provides a persistent pointer suitable as context pointer, not that
of an instance property, compare “Safety with Pointer Argument Conversions” in [Interacting with C Pointers](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=6):

> The pointer that results from these conversions is only guaranteed to be valid for the duration of a call. Even if you pass the same variable, array, or string as multiple pointer arguments, you could receive a different pointer each time. An exception to this is global or static stored variables. You can safely use the address of a global variable as a persistent unique pointer value, e.g.: as a KVO context parameter.